# Wordpress MS Access alternative

Tags: wordpress, forms, webforms

I am looking for a way to create forms and reports with Wordpress. I have been using Scriptcase but it doesn't integrate with wordpress so easily. 
All in all I want to build simple forms and report for our club-financing with a MySQL database for storing the data.

Comment: Are you happy with building the reports with a script yourself, or do you need that to be GUI based point and click?

Comment: GUI point and click would be preferable.